# Joomla: How to set user group access permission for article post?

Tags: joomla, permissions, submit, categories, article

I got several user groups with special rights and categories.

**Example:**
Classes: A, B, C.
Teachers: A, B, C.

Now if "Teacher A" creates an article within his categorie (A) via frontpage he's able to select a permissionlevel for this article (Group A, B, C access).

Is it possible to hide this "access level selection" and give an automatic access level, in this case "access level a", when posting into categorie a?

Thanks for any usefull help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in the past on a client project. I ended up creating a template override for the edit layout by copying components/com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php to templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/form/edit.php. Then, I moved the fields around and hid the regular access level selection container. Then, I performed some logic to get the logged in user to determine what access level they should be selecting, and set that in a hidden field right before the closing form tag, so that when it got submitted, the form would take that value. The field I used looked like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="jform[access]" value="YOUR_GROUP_ACCESS_ID" />
```

So, as Dmitry said, it does take a little bit of work, but it's not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide "access level selection" overriding submit form layout. But for sure some coding will be needed to give an automatic access level. That's not an easy task...

Comment: Hiding does not make sense because "standard access level" for writing articles is wrong (guest only) in my case. Any idea how to set it to, for eg. "registered" by default?

Comment: There is already a default access level in global configuration.